# python substitute words between two points in a text

Tags: python, regex

In the last few days I am dealing with regular expressions. So, let's say that I have a text

```
text = '
1. sometext sometext sometext given as follows:
«book one
title here
part one
1. mpla mpla mpla
2. some text some text «here spesific text»
book two 
1. some text some text.
2. «also» try this in case of emergency.»

book three
part three
directions to home'
```

and I am trying to find all books between '«' and '»'. change it with the word 'chapter' and get the text back. By using regular expression I can't get the result that I want because as far as I can understand regex isn't the best solution for counting how many '»' we have passed so far.

For example 
If I use

```
print re.findall(r'«([book\s\S+]*?)»', data, re.DOTALL)
```

I only get the text until the first '»'. Is there a way to get book one and book two?

I also tried this:

```
print re.findall(r'(?<=«)(?=(book\s\S+))|(?=[^«]*»)(?=(book\s\S+))',data, re.DOTALL)
```

but neither works. Is there a way to get the result or should I use other than regular expressions?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Book two doesn't begin with `<<` ?

Comment: Try using some restriction with a lookahead: `r'(?s)«(book.*?)»(?=\s*(?:\n|$))'`. This will match the closing quote at the end of a line/string.

Comment: @AvinashRaj My expected result should be 'book one', 'book two'. Book two doesn't have '«' because it belongs to the first reference starting at book one. I see that there is a difficulty when I have multiple references inside a reference

Comment: Maybe you could find inspiration from [answers](https://gist.github.com/jpsim/8057500) from [regex golf "balance"](http://regex.alf.nu/11) :^)

Comment: Is there at least a regular expression to find all '«' '»' which are inside '«' '»' ?? I mean how can I get «here spesific text» and «also»? I may remove the start and end of this string and then make anything that I want in my text

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to do this in two parts as follows:

```
print re.findall(r"(book\s\S+)", re.search("«(.*)»", text, re.S).group(1), re.S)
```

This first finds the outer `« »` and then searches inside this for the books.

This gives the following output:

```
['book one', 'book two']
```